# SSIS foreach loop enumerator empty is empty - only when deployed

Tags: loops, foreach, ssis

In SSIS I am using a Foreach loop container to loop through a list of files. 
My project works fine in locally - it finds the files, but when I deploy to SSMS and run it, it gives the error: 
    The for each file enumerator is empty. The for each file enumerator did not find any files that match the pattern, or specified directory was empty.

- The directory I am pointing to is a network location
- I have permissions on this directory.

Has anyone experience this issue before?

Comment: I have seen this issue many times.   Usually it means you're wrong about one of the two bullet points in your question.   Can you post screenshots showing that are correctly pointing to a valid network location, and you are executing as a user that has permission?   Without seeing the proof, I suspect you're probably wrong.

Comment: Does the account used for the SQL Server Agent service have access to this network folder?