# SSIS deployment; For Each File Enumerator is empty

Tags: ssis, ssms

My question is similar to this post: [SSIS foreach loop enumerator empty is empty - only when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025700/ssis-foreach-loop-enumerator-empty-is-empty-only-when-deployed)

**Configuration**: My SSIS package is configured to look through files in a specific network folder, and upload its contents to Server 2.

**Attempt #1** When I run it in Server 1 using SSIS it runs.

**Attempt #2** When I deploy it to Server 2 and use SSMS in Server 1 to run it, I get the file enumerator empty issue.

**Attempt #3** When I deploy it to Server 2 and use SSMS in Server 2 to run it, it runs fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'd guess that the account being used to access the files when you are running a cross server query does not have access to the files. When a query is run cross server, you're credentials may well not be used. Also, if you aren't using SSISDB, then the package will suffer from the double hop issue (if you are using SSISDB, that won't be the case, as you'd already be suffering that problem in Attempts 1 and 3, if you hadn't configured for it).

Comment: When you indicate you are using SSMS to run the package on a given server, does that mean you logon to Server 1, open SSMS, drill through Integration Services Catalog, right click the package to execute? Where does the file live relative to Server 1 and Server 2?

Comment: @billinkc That's basically the exact flow. The file lives in Server 1

Comment: @Larnu, From what I understand (and let me know if I don't understand correctly), going from Server 1 to Server 2 may veto my login credentials and will use the server's instead? If so, that would explain why the enumerator would give me that error (file path not able to be accessed). FYI, I am running it through SSIDB.

Comment: Yes, that could do it, @WichieArtu .